# Copy-Item fails on large file

Tags: powershell, copy

**Update**

After a bit more testing, it seems that the file name is not the problem, as I can copy a new file of 0kb size with the same name without an error. However, the file I am trying to copy is around 8gb in size.

---

I am getting an annoying error when trying to copy a load of files from one drive to another. The `Copy-Item` command looks like this:

```
Copy-Item $oldLocation $newLocation -Recurse -Force
```

Where the parameters are:

```
$oldLocation = 'E:\Documents\Outlook Files\name@domain.co.za.pst'
$newLocation = 'F:\PST Files\EZ-SWAP EX\Documents\Outlook Files\name@domain.co.za.pst'
```

Which I have also tried on its own, in a seperated powershell window, and without the `Recurse` and `Force` switches, with the same result. I also tried the command without putting the paths in parameters and just specifying the strings.

**Note that I am copying from 1 external hard drive to another external hard drive**

They all seem to work except for 1 file, which throws the following error:

> Copy-Item : The parameter is incorrect.
>   At line:4 char:1
>   + Copy-Item $old $new -Force -Recurse
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

This file is unique in that the file name looks like this:

```
 name@domain.co.za.pst
```

Where all the other files are just called

```
filename.pst
```

I'm not sure if the included domain is causing this, but could that be the issue?

If not, what could possible be going wrong here? The error message is not very helpful at all.

My `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` outputs

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  693
```

Comment: What, _exactly_, is the `Copy-Item` command that is being issued when this happens?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thanks for your comment Jeff - I updated my question

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this, `...\name@domain.co.za.pst` is a folder, with files in it?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin No, `name@domain.co.za.pst` is the file name. As I mentioned in the question the code works perfectly for all the other file names (`filename.pst`), but for these `.co.za.pst` files I am seeing the error. I'm guessing this has something to do with file extensions.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Note that I also tried the command in a seperate window where the destination parameter does not include the filename, but it results in the same error

Comment: OK. Your command, as currently written, is equivalent to `Copy-Item -Path $OldLocation -Destination $NewLocation -Force -Recurse`. Instead, try explicitly using `Copy-Item -LiteralPath $OldLocation -Destination $NewLocation -Force -Recurse`. That _should_ prevent any odd interpretation of the file name.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thanks for that Jeff, but I am still seeing the same error. This is really strange.. .could it perhaps have somehing to do with file size?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please copy/paste the exact error message into your question.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I added the rest of the error, but I doubt it will be of much use.

Comment: What happens when you explicitly quote (with double quotes) the variables that you are passing to `Copy-Item`? `Copy-Item -Path "$OldLocation" -Destination "$NewLocation" -Force -Recurse`

Comment: I tried that (see the answer from Mohan). I am pretty sure it is not due to the file name, as I can copy a new file (same name) of 0kb without any issues.

Comment: Check the filesystem type on the destination external hard drive - if it's FAT32, you're hitting a file size limit; FAT can only handle 4GB. Also, if you're doing the copy on Windows 7, regardless of either 32-bit or 64-bit, and regardless of file system, your file size is also capped at 4GB.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'm running it on Windows 10, but after checking the hard-drive file system type, and the destination type is indeed FAT32! Guessing PowerShell automatically checks the file size before trying to copy, because the error appears automatically.. If you add this as an answer I will accept

Comment: Done! See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running on any version of Windows 7 or earlier, or if the destination file system is of type FAT32 regardless of Windows version, you are limited to a maximum file size of 4GB. Since you indicate that the problem file is 8GB, and you've also indicated that a zero-byte file of the same name presents no problem, this is the most likely cause of your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try use double quotation to the path and then try...

```
Copy-Item "C:\PTS\1\Copy-Item\Old\name@domain.co.za.pst" -Destination "C:\PTS\1\Copy-Item\New\" -Recurse
```

Comment: I am seeing the same result